# Using ActiveRecord getters on an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I define custom getter functions for ActiveRecord objects in Ruby that will perform operations on an array of the ActiveRecord objects?

For example, I would like to return weighted averages on an array of objects. So if I have Loan objects (1,2,3) with fields amount (100, 200, 300) and default_rate (.1, .2, .3), then with the normal ActiveRecord functions Loan.find(1).amount should return 100, Loan.find(2).default_rate should return .2.

But if I had Loan.find(2,3).default_rate, I would like it to return the weighted average of the default rates, which is .26. I know I can do this using SQL select statements but how can I "overload" the ActiveRecord getter to allow be to define a function when I call the getter on an array of Loan objects rather than a single Loan object?

The loan table has fields amount id, amount, and default_rate

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  module Collection
    def default_rate
      sum(:default_rate * :amount) / sum(:amount)
    end
  end
end

class LoanGroup
  has_many :loans, :extend => Loan::Collection
end

#Then I try
obj = LoanGroup.where('id < 10')
```

This gives me the error that has_many is undefined in LoanGroup

Comment: here `LoanGroup` would be an extension of `ActiveRecord::Base` and be persisted by the database.  If you just want to call methods on `Loan`, you should do this via a class method on `Loan` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid polluting `Array`'s namespace with methods specific to collections of `Loan` records, you might make a wrapper for such a collection and call your methods on that.

Something like:

```
class LoanArray < Array
  def initialize(*args)
    find(*args)
  end

  def find(*args)
    replace Array.wrap(Loan.find(*args))
    self
  end

  def default_rate
    if length == 1
      self[0].default_rate 
    else
      inject(0) {|mem,loan| mem + loan.defualt_rate } / count
    end
  end
end

# then
arr = LoanArray.new(2,3).default_rate #=> 0.26
arr.find(1,2,3).default_rate          #=> 0.2
arr.length                            #=> 3
arr.find(1)                           #=> [<Loan id=1>]
arr.default_rate                      #=> 0.1
arr.length                            #=> 1
```

---

Original answer below: using an association extension

Use an association extension.  This way the method will be the same whether on a loan, or a collection of loans.

```
class MyClass
  has_many :loans do
    def default_rate
      sum(:default_rate) / count
    end
  end
end

obj = MyClass.find(1)
obj.loans.first.default_rate               #=> 0.1
obj.loans.default_rate                     #=> 0.2
obj.loans.where(:id => [2,3]).default_rate #=> 0.26
```

If you wanted to keep the logic for loans in the `Loan` class, you could also write the extension there, e.g.:

```
class Loan
  module Collection
    def default_rate
      sum(:default_rate) / count
    end

    # plus other methods, as needed, e.g.
    def average_amount
      sum(:amount) / count
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  has_many :loans, :extend => Loan::Collection
end
```

Edit: as @Santosh points out `association.find` does not return a relation, so it will not work here.  You'd have to use `where` or some other method which returns a relation.

Comment: Will this "MyClass.find(1).loans.find(2,3).default_rate" work? Because      MyClass.find(1).loans.find(2,3) this will return an array not ActiveRecord::Relation object.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  You'd have to use `where` in this case to keep it a relation.  Sorry, my rails is rusty ;-).  Editing to fix.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for but I'm having trouble making it work. Does MyClass need to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: Yep.  That would be whatever class you're using that has a `loans` association.  If there is no such class though, and you're just doing queries on `Loan`, then you probably want one of the other answers.

Comment: I should probably note that this answer is for the current version of rails 3.  I think that the syntax for calling methods inside of associations has changed somewhat over Rails' lifetime.

Comment: Correct. There is no other class. It is just a collection of loans. I am attempting to create a separate object that is really just one or more Loan objects, with no additional data or table.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Loved your solutions...very detailed and nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can write class method for this.

```
class Loan
  def self.default_rate
    sum = 0
    all.each do |loan|
      sum += loan.default_rate
    end
    sum / all.count
  end
end
```

Then

```
Loan.where(:id => [2, 3]).default_rate
```

Other solution if you want to use Loan.find(2,3) then you need to override the Array class.

```
class Array   
  def default_rate
    sum = 0     
    self.each do |loan|
      sum += loan.default_rate
    end
    sum / self.count
  end
end

Loan.find(2, 3).default_rate
```

Comment: The problem with #2 is that you really shouldn't extend Array in this way.  It would be perfectly fine though to implement something like `Array#average(property)` which tries to sum and average a property of an Array.  In which case you could call something like `Loan.find(2,3).average(:default_rate)`, and it wouldn't pollute Array with inappropriate methods.

Comment: @numbers1311407 I agree with you. But he wants custom method on array objects so I wrote this #2 solution for him.

Comment: Of course, and in a small-scoped application you can probably get away with it.  But as even [some popular and pervasive libraries](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rush/blob/master/lib/rush/commands.rb#L19) pollute `Array` in inexcusable ways, I tend to try not to encourage the habit.

Comment: It would seem to me that this is creating an awful lot of queries to the database. I am essentially trying to do: SELECT sum(amount*default_rate)/sum(amount) FROM Loans

Comment: ActiveRecord has database summing built in, you could write the class method `Loan.default_rate() sum(:default_rate) / count; end` and it would just perform an SQL sum and count query.  Note that works with @Santosh's first example, not the 2nd.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that it is not being performed on the whole table. I am creating an array of objects from the loan table (essentially a subset of the Loan table), then trying to perform that SQL on the subset of the Loan table

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bit more freedom by not doing this as a class method; you could have a method header of `default_rate (*args)` to allow multiple arguments to be passed in using the splat operator, then check the `args` length. It can be done quite nicely recursively:

```
def default_rate(*args)
  sum = 0
  if args.length == 1
    return array_name[arg-1] # guessing that's how you store the actual var
  else
    args.each do |arg|
      sum += default_rate arg
    end
  end
  return sum/args.length
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accept introducing a named scope, than you can exploit the fact scopes have the methods of the classes they are defined on. This way, having

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, where(:color => 'red')

  def self.sum
    # consider #all as the records you are processing - the scope will
    # make it return neccessary ones only
    all.map(&:id).sum
  end
end

Shirt.red.sum
```

will yield you a sum id red shirts' ids (as opposed to Shirt.sum will yield a sum of all ids).

Having your BL layed out this way not only makes it cleaner, but also enables it to be re-used (you can invoke the #sum method on any scope, no matter how complex it is and you will still get valid results). In addition to that, it appears to be easily readable and doesn't involve any magic (well, almost :)

Hope this would clean you code up a bit :)